# Testing running over an half hour

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I'm building a project in maven from eclipse, I ran clean install , and now I'm in my test phase .. and now I have this usual message that tests are running :

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
```

and nothing is happening for half an hour now .. when I bring up the maven console it gives me what I executed :

```
2/16/10 11:42:37 AM CET: Build type none : clean install
```

Nothing about what is happening to the tests? what can I do ? what is going on ? how can I know that this is working or not?

Comment: What happen when you run your unit tests outside Maven? For example with Eclipse?

Comment: I haven't really tried that at all, I'm using eclipse from start never made any problem ?

Comment: Have you tried getting a thread-dump (Ctrl+\ on Linux / SIGQUIT) and see where the code is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repository was down the whole day it was stuck there

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell you where is the problem.

The first thing to do is to define if the problem come from your tests or from Maven.

What you can try is to select the `src/test/java` (or the root directory of your unit test classes) in your Package explorer in Eclipse, then right-click and select "Run as > JUnit test". If the behavior is the same, i.e. it takes forever to execute, then the problem is directly due to your tests. Eclipse will show which test is taking too much time in the JUnit perspective...